# MySQL COUNT syntax in bigger query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to create a query that will return all the jobs published by a specific company, and a count of the total people who applied to this job. the first part works fine - I get all the jobs and everything I need:

```
$query = "SELECT *,j.job_id as jid, c.name as city_name ".
         "FROM jobs j JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = j.job_area ".
         "JOIN positions p ON p.position_id = j.job_position ".
         "JOIN fields f ON f.id = j.job_field ".
         "JOIN cities c ON j.job_city = c.id ".
         "JOIN jobTypes jt ON j.job_type = jt.job_id " .
         "JOIN companies comp ON j.job_company = comp.company_id ".
         "LEFT JOIN jobApplications ja ON ".
              "ja.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND ".
              "j.job_id = ja.job_id WHERE j.job_company='$company_id'";
```

The thing is, that I want to add each result row the number of applicants for the job from the jobApplications table... I tried to add a COUNT column to the query, which works great by itself:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobApplications ja WHERE ja.job_id=j.job_id
```

when added to the first big query, I didn't manage to make this work even on the syntax level, so i'm not sure if it works at all...

I tried to add the last query to the select area of the main query, but I always get a syntax error right after the 'ja.job_id=j.job_id' in the end of the count query...

Is this even possible ?

I hope the question is clear, I know there are many tables included here...
Thanks for the time and help!

Comment: Thanks Rufinus, I'll try to better format the query next time (when I try it always breaks my 'code' tag...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know your PK of jobApplications, but this might work.

```
$query = "SELECT *,j.job_id as jid, c.name as city_name, COUNT(ja.<primary key>) ".
     "FROM jobs j JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = j.job_area ".
     "JOIN positions p ON p.position_id = j.job_position ".
     "JOIN fields f ON f.id = j.job_field ".
     "JOIN cities c ON j.job_city = c.id ".
     "JOIN jobTypes jt ON j.job_type = jt.job_id " .
     "JOIN companies comp ON j.job_company = comp.company_id ".
     "LEFT JOIN jobApplications ja ON ".
          "ja.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND ".
          "j.job_id = ja.job_id WHERE j.job_company='$company_id' ".
     "GROUP By jid";
```

Comment: thanks, It worked... never spent 3 hours on a single query but maybe its a good sign :)

Comment: OK, It works great, but I just understood I don't exactly understand why. Maybe you could explain... I understand we count the ja.field. (I don't have an ID for this table so I used the user_id) I understand we group by the job_id because we are looking for jobs, but how does it count only the applicants for the specific job? thanks :)

Comment: if you join a table with a 1:N (or n:m for that matter) relation. and dont group you would have multiple rows from the first table for every match in the second table. if you just want to have the number of rows matching in the second table you use count() but to let sql now what you want to count you have to group the first table. see http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php too.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(ja2.job_id) FROM jobApplications ja2 WHERE ja2.job_id=j.job_id group by j.job_id), *,j.job_id as jid, c.name as city_name FROM jobs j JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = j.job_area" .
" JOIN positions p ON p.position_id = j.job_position JOIN fields f ON f.id = j.job_field "
 ." JOIN cities c ON j.job_city = c.id JOIN jobTypes jt ON j.job_type = jt.job_id " .
 "JOIN companies comp ON j.job_company = comp.company_id LEFT JOIN jobApplications ja ON ja.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND j.job_id = ja.job_id WHERE j.job_company='$company_id'";
```

Comment: Ok, managed to make it kinda work, but the thing is that it does not recognise for some reason the comparison fields in the where. This is what I tried: SELECT *,j.job_id as jid, c.name as city_name, (select count(*) from jobApplications WHERE jobApplications.job_id = j.job_id)
FROM.... any idea?

Comment: Syntax wise - It works, no errors... The thing is that the comparison in the WHERE part dosn't consider the values passed from the main select query, I hope i'm clear... - the COUNT works, but brings everything and not only 'WHERE ja.job_id = j.job_id'

Comment: @Yanipan you need to make a `group by` then. Try what I put now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use GROUP

```
SELECT *,j.job_id as jid, c.name as city_name, COUNT(jobApplications.*)
FROM jobs j JOIN areas a ON a.area_id = j.job_area 
JOIN positions p ON p.position_id = j.job_position 
JOIN fields f ON f.id = j.job_field 
JOIN cities c ON j.job_city = c.id 
JOIN jobTypes jt ON j.job_type = jt.job_id 
JOIN companies comp ON j.job_company = comp.company_id 
LEFT JOIN jobApplications ja ON 
ja.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND 
j.job_id = ja.job_id WHERE j.job_company='$company_id'
GROUP BY jid
```

Hope it helps :)